# Json - Flatten Key and Values in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

In a Hive table having a record JSON column value as: {"XXX": ["123","456"],"YYY": ["246","135"]} and ID as ABC

Need to flatten it as below in Hive query.

| Key | Value | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| XXX | 123 | ABC |
| XXX | 456 | ABC |
| YYY | 246 | ABC |
| YYY | 135 | ABC |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following uses `get_json_object` to extract json keys before using  `regexp_replace` and `split` to convert the remaining values to arrays. With the assistance of `explode` and `lateral views` from the resulting subquery, the data has been extracted. The full reproducible example is below:

```sql
WITH input_df AS (
    SELECT '{"XXX": ["123","456"],"YYY": ["246","135"]}' my_col
)
SELECT
    t.key,
    kv.kval as value
FROM (
    SELECT
         explode(map(
             'XXX',
             split(regexp_replace(get_json_object(my_col,'$.XXX'),'"|\\[|\\]',''),','),
             'YYY',
             split(regexp_replace(get_json_object(my_col,'$.YYY'),'"|\\[|\\]',''),',')
         )) 
    FROM
        input_df
) t LATERAL VIEW explode(t.value) kv as kval
```

You may use the query below if your table/view is named `input_df` and your json column is `my_col`

```sql
SELECT
    t.key,
    kv.kval as value
FROM (
    SELECT
         explode(map(
             'XXX',
             split(regexp_replace(get_json_object(my_col,'$.XXX'),'"|\\[|\\]',''),','),
             'YYY',
             split(regexp_replace(get_json_object(my_col,'$.YYY'),'"|\\[|\\]',''),',')
         )) 
    FROM
        input_df
) t LATERAL VIEW explode(t.value) kv as kval
```

##### Response To Updated Question 1:

```sql
SELECT
    t.key,
    kv.kval as value,
    'ABC' as ID
FROM (
    SELECT
         explode(map(
             'XXX',
             split(regexp_replace(get_json_object(my_col,'$.XXX'),'"|\\[|\\]',''),','),
             'YYY',
             split(regexp_replace(get_json_object(my_col,'$.YYY'),'"|\\[|\\]',''),',')
         )) 
    FROM
        input_df
) t LATERAL VIEW explode(t.value) kv as kval
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks you ggordan, it works. Additional one column ID needs in the result. can you please modify the query accordingly?

Comment: The answer has been updated. Please upvote and mark answer as accepted answer to assist other S/O users with similar question. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I am not explained clearly.                                                                                                   ID is not static column , for next record ID value may change as AAA. How should I achieve it?

Comment: modified the query, it is throwing error. pls guide me to fix this

Comment: Please add a different question with the complete query you used (i.e. including the modification), error you received, sample data to reproduce the error and stacktrace if possible.

Comment: yes sir.. Posted a different question, with same title

Comment: Let me know how vote or share the link to vote

Comment: subject : Json - Additional column value added to Flatten Key and Values in Hive